# Continuous data sending and receiving

Tags: java, sockets

I'm very new to socket programming. I have a requirement on continuously sending and receiving data between client and server. Below the process flow needs to be done.

1. Client sends "Client Hello" message to Server.
2. Server sends "Server hello" message to Client.
3. Client Sends "What is your server id?" message to Server
4. Server sends "My ID is #1" message to Client.
5. Client sends "Thank you" message to Server.
6. Server send "You are welcome" message to client

I tried to do this using Java sockets API. But i can't send multiple messages using a one socket. only 1 and 2 messages were able to transmit. Can someone tell me a way to achieve this requirement? Highly appreciate if someone give me an advise on this.

This is the server side program

```
package socketserver;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SocketServer{   

    public static void main(String args[]){
        final int SocketServerPORT = 4000;

        try{                
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
            System.out.println("Server is started with port"+ serverSocket.getLocalPort());           


            System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            //Receiving Client Hello
            System.out.println(input.readLine());                    

            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            //Sending Server Hello
            output.write("Server Hello");
            output.flush();

            //Recieving Client message asking regarding Server ID
            System.out.println(input.readLine());

            //Sending Server ID to client
            output.write("MY Server ID is #1");
            output.flush();

            //Recieving Client Thank you message
            System.out.println(input.readLine());

            //Sending Welcome message to Client
            output.write("You are welcome.");
            output.flush();

            output.close();
            input.close();               
            socket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {                  
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}
```

Below is the Client Side program

```
package socketclient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SocketClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int socketServerPORT = 4000;
        final String host="127.0.0.1";

        try {
                Socket clientSocket=new Socket(host,socketServerPORT);

                PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

                //Sending Client Hello
                output.println("Client Hello");                
                output.flush();

                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));    

                //Receiving Server Hello
                System.out.println(input.readLine());

                //Asking for Server ID
                output.println("What is your Server ID");
                output.flush();

                //Receving Server ID
                System.out.println(input.readLine());

                //Sending Thank you message to Server
                output.println("Thank you.");
                output.flush();

                //Receving Welcome message from Server
                System.out.println(input.readLine());                


                output.close();              
                input.close();      
                clientSocket.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: "`But i can't send multiple messages using a one socket. only 1 and 2 messages were able to transmit. `" ITs not clear if your code is only working two messages "long" or if your not able to serve multiple clients at the same time. Please clarify this. Code you've already written is also appeciated since it helps identifying the problem.

Comment: I have added my source code above. This program i wrote only for  serve a one client. I don't need to serve multiple clients at the same time. My only requirement is to send these messages between server and client. When i am running this program i can't see any output. Can you give me an support to overcome this issue.

Comment: There is no SSLEngine or NIO or SSL here. Please don't use irrelevant tags. "Can't" is not a problem description.

Comment: " continuously sending" no program can send continuously. But it could run continually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading lines but you aren't writing lines. The readLine() method blocks until a line terminator or end of stream occurs. You need to either append \n to each message or use println() instead of write().